# datalist different behaviour with FF/chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox

I am facing an issue with the datalist element when the list of values exceeds 20 values.
The list in Chrome is complete whereas it is limited to 20 values while using Firefox.
Is there a way to solve this issue?
Is it also possible to display an arrow on the right side of the field in Firefox as in Chrome?

Thanks for your help!

Stéphane

Here below is my code:

```html
<table class="area" id="ContextTabl" style="display: block">
<tr>
<td><input list="lstCont1" type="text" id="Choice"><datalist id="lstCont1">
<option value="Choice 1">Choice 1</option>
<option value="Choice 2">Choice 2</option>
<option value="Choice 3">Choice 3</option>
<option value="Choice 4">Choice 4</option>
<option value="Choice 5">Choice 5</option>
<option value="Choice 6">Choice 6</option>
<option value="Choice 7">Choice 7</option>
<option value="Choice 8">Choice 8</option>
<option value="Choice 9">Choice 9</option>
<option value="Choice 10">Choice 10</option>
<option value="Choice 11">Choice 11</option>
<option value="Choice 12">Choice 12</option>
<option value="Choice 13">Choice 13</option>
<option value="Choice 14">Choice 14</option>
<option value="Choice 15">Choice 15</option>
<option value="Choice 16">Choice 16</option>
<option value="Choice 17">Choice 17</option>
<option value="Choice 18">Choice 18</option>
<option value="Choice 19">Choice 19</option>
<option value="Choice 20">Choice 20</option>
<option value="Choice 21">Choice 21</option>
<option value="Choice 22">Choice 22</option>
<option value="Choice 23">Choice 23</option>
<option value="Choice 24">Choice 24</option>
<option value="Choice 25">Choice 25</option>
</datalist></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Also doesn't work in Safari - http://caniuse.com/#feat=datalist Can't you use a normal <select></select> ?

Comment: A normal <select></select> will indeed allow listing all the values both in FF and Chrome but then I will loose the datalist autocomplete functionality